# Podman play kube working with sudo but not without

Tags: podman

I am currently running the default podman 3.4.4 on a Ubuntu 22.04.2 (amd) server.

At first I ran the snippet you can find [here](https://gerov.eu/posts/traefik-for-podman/#create-traefik-container) (non-sudo) and it worked perfectly fine. I generated the kube file from it and tweaked it to use env variables instead. Now basically the same definition won't work with `podman play kube`. Running `sudo podman play kube`, it works perfectly fine but without sudo, I get the following error message:

```bash
Error: k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.5: image not known
```

This is the same for all of my pod definitions, not only Traefik. Not even the standard hello-world works, so also not a problem with ports.

Cheers,
Moe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it was fixed after recreating my user account. At first I created it with `useradd` and the second time with `adduser`. As for why, I also still have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same error when running Zombienet + Podman 3.4.4 on Ubuntu 22.04

At first, I thought the reason is [k8s.gcr.io Redirect to registry.k8s.io](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/03/10/image-registry-redirect/).

However, after I manually pull the image, then retry, it works!

```bash
podman pull k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.5
```

I still don't know the real reason behind this error.